# How to get Product custom image

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created an attribute for image as "billede_hover" ,
See Admin screen-short below,
[image]

When i am upload image,
And also noted in media folder create `billede_hover` but it's alway empty,
[image]
Please suggest

I am using below code but it's not working

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'billede_hover')->resize(400,300); ?>
```